# Return Name of Months and Not Integer DATEADD Function

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a query in a stored procedure which I am trying to use to store the current date in a database as a a string.
For example, the query should store:

```
May 2015
```

Here is the query:

```
DECLARE @daterun varchar(max)

DECLARE @DATE_AP dateTime
DECLARE @month_AP varchar(max)
DECLARE @year_AP varchar(max)

SET @DATE_AP= DATEADD(month, -1, GETDATE())
SET @year_AP = YEAR(@DATE_AP)
SET @month_AP = MONTH(@DATE_AP)


PRINT @year_AP
SELECT @daterun = 'UPDATE  [dbo].[tabimp] SET [dbo].[tabimp].[date] ='+ @month_AP+ @year_AP

EXEC (@daterun)
```

I realize @month_AP returns an integer value. How do i return the name of the month instead?

Comment: if you want to store a date in a database, just store the date not the varchar due to formating options. Do the formating client-side.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the ['DateName'](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174395.aspx) function:

```
SET @month_AP = DATENAME(Month, @DATE_AP)
```